# Laravel Regex Validation Error

Tags: php, laravel

I use regex validation in Laravel. But error occures. I want to control, it is image or not. Image extension can be .jpg, .png or only .jp2. Here is my implementation :

```
protected $rules = [
      'preview_path'  => 'required|regex:[^.*\.(jpg|png)$]',
      'slide_path'    => 'required|regex:[^.*\.(jp2)$]'
];
```

Error :

> preg_match(): No ending matching delimiter ']' found

**EDIT**

I am not send a file, i send just string path as a json. So i can not use mime type validation.

Comment: why dont you use `mimes` for this ?  `'preview_path' => 'required|mimes:jpg,png'
'slide_path'=>'required|mimes:jp2'`

Comment: @Rodrane it is REST API part, i send path as a json (string) not file. Mimes doesn't work.

Comment: you are not asking your question clearly then obviously they are not images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should work

```
protected $rules = [ 
    'preview_path' => ['required|regex:/^.*\.(jpg|png)$/'], 
    'slide_path' => ['required|regex:/^.*\.(jp2)$/'] 
];
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this for extension validation which is better than regex
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-mimes